# Is there a way to get Azure AD user's information using KQL

Tags: azure-active-directory, kql

I am trying to get user's information from Azure AD directly, like DisplayName and UserPrincipalName, using KQL. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Generally User attributes/properties are not available by default. User activity/audit logs etc can be queried. However you need to provide more context. Do you want to get user properties/attributes or something else from a different Azure/O365/M365 product?Your question is a bit vague, if possible could you describe your problem, what you want to achieve? It will be easier to understand and assess for a solution then.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to join the OfficeActivity logs with any logs that can provide the DisplayName of the user instead of the OfficeObjectID (the Full name). OfficeObjectID may contains distinct values, like for example for two users with the same display name, it would look like this:

Doe, John - 1
Doe, John - 2

While their display name is Doe, John.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up exporting the needed user's attributes using PowerShell and copying the output into a Blob container, then ran the below KQL query to join the file content with the query:

```
let UserAtt = externaldata (UserPrincipalName:string, DisplayName:string) [
@"URL to the file location in the blob storage"
h@"?sp="Secret token"
] with (format="csv", ignoreFirstRecord=true);
UserAtt
| join kind=inner (
OfficeActivity
  | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
  | where (Operation =~ "Set-Mailbox" and Parameters contains 'ForwardingSmtpAddress') 
  or (Operation =~ 'New-InboxRule' and Parameters contains 'ForwardTo')
  | extend parsed=parse_json(Parameters)
  | extend fwdingDestination_initial = (iif(Operation=~"Set-Mailbox", tostring(parsed[1].Value), tostring(parsed[2].Value)))
  | where isnotempty(fwdingDestination_initial)
  | extend fwdingDestination = iff(fwdingDestination_initial has "smtp", (split(fwdingDestination_initial,":")[1]), fwdingDestination_initial )
  | parse fwdingDestination with * '@' ForwardedtoDomain 
  | parse UserId with *'@' UserDomain
  | extend subDomain = ((split(strcat(tostring(split(UserDomain, '.')[-2]),'.',tostring(split(UserDomain, '.')[-1])), '.') [0]))
  | where ForwardedtoDomain !contains subDomain
  | extend Result = iff( ForwardedtoDomain != UserDomain ,"Mailbox rule created to forward to External Domain", "Forward rule for Internal domain")
  | extend ClientIPAddress = case( ClientIP has ".", tostring(split(ClientIP,":")[0]), ClientIP has "[", tostring(trim_start(@'[[]',tostring(split(ClientIP,"]")[0]))), ClientIP )
  | extend Port = case(
  ClientIP has ".", (split(ClientIP,":")[1]),
  ClientIP has "[", tostring(split(ClientIP,"]:")[1]),
  ClientIP
  )
  | project TimeGenerated, UserId, UserDomain, subDomain, Operation, ForwardedtoDomain, ClientIPAddress, Result, Port, OriginatingServer, OfficeObjectId, fwdingDestination
  | extend timestamp = TimeGenerated, AccountCustomEntity = UserId, IPCustomEntity = ClientIPAddress, HostCustomEntity = OriginatingServer)
 on $left.UserPrincipalName == $right.AccountCustomEntity
```